# position:fixed does not work in Chrome Mobile

Tags: css, google-chrome, mobile

If there is any element larger than ca. 400 px (here the green div) the element with position:fixed stops to be fixed. In Firefox Mobile it's ok. "Overflow:hidden or scroll" doesn't help.

this is my code:

```
<!-- <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>fix test</title>
<style>
body {
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 900px;
}
.fix {
    position: fixed;
    top: 110px;
    background-color: orange;
}
.large {
    width: 650px;
    height: 88px;
    background-color: green;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="fix">
    <h1> should be fixed </h1>
</div>
<h1>sample text</h1>
<h1>sample text</h1>
<h1>sample text</h1>
<h1>sample text</h1>
<div class="large"></div>
<h1>sample text</h1>
<h1>sample text</h1>
<h1>sample text</h1>
<h1>sample text</h1>
<h1>sample text</h1>
<h1>sample text</h1>
<h1>sample text</h1>
<h1>sample text</h1>
<h1>sample text</h1>
<h1>sample text</h1>
<h1>sample text</h1>
<h1>sample text</h1>
<h1>sample text</h1>
<h1>sample text</h1>
</body>
</html>
 -->
```

What can I do . I want to have some pictures wider than 400 pixels.

here is my example: [my link](https://www.hochweber.ch/fixed-position.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Its work for me , it looks like not working because the body height is too large to display in the mobile device. 
try to use [ top:0] in your fix class and see the difference.

Comment: Rap, thank you, but top:0 doesn't help. As I said, the problem is only in Chrome Mobile.